# I can not reassign a prompt result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a tiny program (average of notes) that request via prompt a number. I want that if the input it's not a number, the alert command show a number is needed.

If you check the code, prompt input uses Number() to convert the string to a number. But if I type some string the result is NaN and I tried to reasign the note variable in the while loop but something is wrong because the program continues executing the remaining code.

```js
let subjects = Number(prompt('Type quantity of subjects: '));
let sum = 0;

while (isNaN(subjects)) {

  alert('Type a number');
  subjects = Number(prompt('Type quantity of subjects: '));

}

for (i = 1; i <= notes; i++) {
  note = Number(prompt('Type note of subject' + i + ': '));
  sum += note;
}
average = sum / subjects;

alert(average.toFixed(2));
```

I expect the program ask (via prompt) for a number everytime it's not.

Comment: I tried running it and it's working. The only problem is that notes is undefined. Maybe you wanted to write `subjects` instead of `notes` (in `for` loop)?

Comment: Yep,it was an error.  It's subjects instead of notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `notes` is `undefined` which is used in `for` loop. I think `subjects` should be there. And also convert `note` to Number. And use [Unary Plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()). for converting string to number. Its faster.

```js
let subjects = +prompt('Type quantity of subjects: ');
let sum = 0;

while (isNaN(subjects)) {
  alert('Type a number');
  subjects = +prompt('Type quantity of subjects: ');
}

for (let i = 1; i <= subjects; i++) {
  note = +prompt('Type note of subject' + i + ': ');
  sum += +note;
}
average = sum / subjects;

alert(average.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: This works like I nedeed. I dont know why in JS Bin page doesn't work properly, even in codepen at 3 attempt to type a number, finally throw an error (NaN). Works perfectly in this page by the way. Thanks for Unary Plus advice, didn't know it.